# Fighting game with alien or dinosaur-like characters, from the early 2000s, running on Windows

Tags: gaming, identify-this-game

I’m really hoping someone knows this game. I think it came out late 90s or early 2000s for Windows. The gameplay was Mortal Kombat style where two players could dual sharing the keyboard. Other dot points I can recall:

- the characters were alien/dinosaur in appearance
- a rage meter and your power increased when it was full
- one character looked like a pterodactyl that could flap/fly and had a special move that transformed itself into a drill or rhino horn that drilled across the map attacking
- another character resembled a stegosaurus in shape, with maybe a smooth back and 3 spikes on it’s tail and it’s special attack involved it’s tail curling over it’s head and shooting the 3 spikes as projectiles across the screen
- a third character resembled a lizard and it spat out a black blob
- there was blood but I recall it being heavily stylized, possibly not red, very alien looking
- pretty sure there were other characters but the demo version of the game was limited to those characters
- there was a training mode where you could practice moves against a punching bag with a dinosaur cover
- the name could have had ‘alien’ in it and similar to ‘blood lust’ or ‘blood spor’ (searching on these names don’t show the game so they aren’t correct but I think in the right vein)

The game has evaded me for some time - does anyone recognise it?

Thanks for reading,

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found it, been looking for years.
It's called Xenophage: Alien Bloodsport.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOD5HITHZZQ This is a clip of a longplay, pterodactyl fight starts at 10:10

Comment: Thank you! This was it - think my recollection was off a bit but well done finding it!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean 'Primal Rage'? Title in your head was probably 'Bloody Roar'.

I have no knowledge whatsoever about these games, but had a fun hour strolling through 'Windows fighting games around 2000' on Bing :-) Thank you!

Marc

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It wasn’t quite what I was looking for but it was a solid guess and I might still check it out :)